# How do I iterate through matrix elements matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have the task of creating a piece of matlab code that uses the sieve of Eratosthenes to find the list of prime numbers up to N. I have created a loop that finds the non primes and then finds the index value of them in the list of 2 to N. How do I get my program to take these index values element by element and set the corresponding positions in my zero matrix to one?

Also for my assignment I cannot use the in built isprime functions.

My code so far:

```
function [p,c] = sieve(N)

N = input('Please type an integer greater than 1: ');

a = ones(1,N); %Non-primes are set to 0

for k = 2:N
```

How does k:k:end work, I'm guessing it adds k until it reaches N.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example may be by forming a smaller array or so?

Comment: Make a new question. It's bad practice here to add a new question on top of your old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

As OP may still be confused, I'll just give a new answer (not dissimilar to my previous wrong one)

```
 x=zeros(100,1);
 for i=2:100; 
    x(2*i:i:end)=1; 
 end; find(~x)
```

You just need to go from `2*i` rather than `i`....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your matrix of zeros is called "numbersthatareprime" and your prime indices are called "primeindices":

```
numbersthatareprime(primeindices)=1
```

Comment: Careful. `isprime` is an actual function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isprime.html.  This will overshadow the function with that variable.  However, this is the correct answer so +1 for you.

Comment: V good point - I had a case recently where I accidently overwrote the inbuilt "lines" function then was pulling my hair out when coloring lines in a subsequent figure was giving me errors!

Comment: :D... I hear you.  A workaround is to use the the `builtin` function that will explicitly call the built-in version of the function instead of an overloaded function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html.... but it of course minimizes headaches if you don't do it anyway.

Comment: In my case, I didn't realise I had until I looked at the very top and very bottom of my script. "lines" seems like a natural variable to use when pulling in a text file line by line... Don't do it!

Answer (score 1):

That's just a matter of using your array to index into your vector.  As such, create a vector of all zeros that is `N` in length, then assuming you have the list of prime numbers up to `N` which is called `prim`, just do:

```
vec = zeros(1, N);
vec(prim) = 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't really need a matrix. Just a list of values!

```
X=zeros(10000,1);
for i=2:100
   X(i:i:end) = 1
end
```

Here, the indexing `i:i:end` means

- `[2,4,6,8,...]` when `i==2`
- `[3,6,9,...]` when `i==3`
- etc

So it sets all the multiples of 2, then all the multiples of 3 etc., creating your seive.

Note that you only need to go up to `sqrt(N)`.

Then you can just do `find(X)` to get the primes!

Comment: I don't think this is correct. i:i:end indexing in a loop? 2:2:end, then 3:3:end, then 4:4:end, etc? What does this do?

Comment: The objective is to determine a binary matrix that determines what is prime.

Comment: But you are iterating over all the primes and their multiples too!! 2:100 includes e.g. 5, 7, 13 - these will all be set to 1.

Comment: This determines a binary array that determines what is prime. (i.e. zeros)

Comment: Ah yes you are right @HughNolan! I'll leave this wrong answer here as it illustrates part of what the OP will have to do...

Comment: You will get a vector of all ones as the output.

Comment: Surely this would lead to 2 being considered not prime as it will be marked 1. What does the end command do exactly?

Comment: As there's still no accepted answer, I'd like to point out that changing the starting index of `X(i:` to `X(2*i:` does what is required, and I've added another answer with this modification. Crucially I think this is what the OP wanted to know.